# How to setup PyCharm for Docker inside Vagrant?

Tags: docker, vagrant, pycharm

I've a project that's running Docker in Vagrant.

The python interpreter is inside the Docker containter.

How do I set up PyCharm so that it can use this interpreter.

The Dockerfile is:

```
FROM python:3.5.1-onbuild
```

The docker-compose.yaml is the following:

```
web:
  restart: always
  build: .
  ports: 
    - "80:80"
  expose:
    - "80"
  links:
    - postgres:postgres
  volumes:
    - .:/usr/src/app/
  env_file: .env
  command: /usr/local/bin/gunicorn --reload -w 2 -b :80  hello:app 

data:
  image: postgres:latest
  volumes:
    - /var/lib/postgresql
  command: "true"

postgres:
  restart: always
  image: postgres:latest
  volumes_from:
    - data
  ports:
    - "5432:5432"
```

I already tried with the standard options but it seems that you only can choose either docker or vagrant:
[docker or vagrant](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uNGD3.png)

Thanks

Comment: PyCharm doesn't yet support Docker Compose: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-17573

Answer (score 0):

Docker-compose support is added to the last version of PyCharm. Here's how to solve the issue, using the latest version of PyCharm.
[Configure PyCharm interpreter with docker-compose inside Vagrant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36058949/configure-pycharm-interpreter-with-docker-compose-inside-vagrant/36370813#36370813)